# boot problem system stops ubuntu-GNOME 13.04

Tags: boot, gnome

> **message:** give up waiting for root device
>   ....
>   ALERT! `/dev/disk/by-uuid4ec71b51-5f7c`... does not exist
>   Dropping to a shell
>
> BusyBox v1.20 ...
>   Enter `'help'` for a list of built in commands.
>   (initramfs) -

**hardware:** msi760-gm  AMD fx6100 64bit

I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me? Thanks i.a. Henk Kohn

Comment: What did you do before this started happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can get to your desktop still

> cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt
>
> lvm vgchange -a y
>
> exit

im not sure does this work for you but it worked atleast for me, because i have my ubuntu on sda5, you could still try it. Then you will be getting to desktop (its useful) but it wont solve it, you can get to desktop with it.

Im having the same problem, but that is useful to get to desktop.

You could try to use Boot-repair from liveCD or USB.

Comment: Actually the last update solded even this, i dont know, when you get to desktop update with updatemanager, it should fix it (atleast for me)